# What is the reason behind donating our own hair to God?

Tags: vedas, puranas, superstitions

Most of the devotees have a regular habit of donating their hair for their beloved Gods.Men ready for full hair donation and there is a priority for women such as donating of few of their hair (it is named as 'Pumudi' in Tamil side).
Famous temples like **Tripati,Palani** are well known for these donations.

The question is,

**Is there any puranas and Vedas evidence or reasons for this practises**?

If so who actually starts these practises?

Comment: I think,the devotees vow before God that if one of their wishes is fulfilled they will shave off their heads in return.Once those wishes are fulfilled they do as they have promised to God..Its not that they are donating hair .

Comment: See [Why does one get their head tonsured and offer the hair to Lord Venkateswara in Tirupati?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3137/3500)

Comment: Not only donating hair, wearing ear rings, etc., is also practiced in Hinduism. It is not an act of donating hair but It is an act of donating one's **beauty** for the God. Generally in Hinduism if one has sacrificed something he will get something in return. Here in your case the person has sacrificed his/her beauty by donating his/her hair to God in return to satisfy his wish

Comment: @AnilKumar The story in the link may be the history of Tirupati. But I wish for the root of this practise.

Comment: @PonmariSubramanian Vakula Devi gave her hair to Srinivasa when Srinivasa was hit. So, he likes everyone who gives hair.

Comment: @AnilKumar It is the good for Tripati. Then what about Palani and other temples which are apart from Tripati or Lord Srinivasa?