# Which purana states the story of Neela Devi lending hair to Lord Vishnu for covering scar?

Tags: identification-request, venkateshwara

Which Puranas has the story of Neela Devi giving hair to Lord Vishnu for covering his scar on head? This is the story famous for giving hair at Tirupati Venkateshwara temple.

Comment: Related - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3137/why-does-one-get-their-head-tonsured-and-offer-the-hair-to-lord-venkateswara-in