# What is the reason behind tonsuring?

Tags: rituals

I've heard varying reasons behind tonsuring, some that it is a way of shedding one's ego, others that the hair is a sacrifice.  Which reasoning is correct?

Comment: sins are stored in hairs. cutting them off gets rid of them. for new-born baby, tonsuring is done 1 year after birth. What sins can a new-born commit ? Well, it's for pre-natal sins - maybe those committed by mom, and the dirt (blood,stool,urine) associated with birth are also stored in the hair. for regular men, shaving once a month (including body hair) gets rids of sins.. so that we can commit fresh sins going forward :). but the tuft at back of head (shikha) should not be tonsured, because it has religious significance for both Deva & Apara karya.

Comment: I too heard it as shedding of ego.

Comment: Related or Possible duplicate of [Why does one get their head tonsured and offer the hair to Lord Venkateswara in Tirupati?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3137/3500)

Comment: I saw about the Tirupati temple, that is where I am confused, is it a sacrifice or just shedding one's ego?